# Evaluate $( \sqrt{288} + \sqrt{119})^{3/2} - ( \sqrt{288} - \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$

Tags: radicals

I need to find the value of

$$( \sqrt{288} + \sqrt{119})^{3/2} - ( \sqrt{288} - \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$$

I tried using the identity $a^{3} - b^{3}$ but couldn't reach very far and got stuck.

Comment: What equation? What is there to solve?

Comment: I mean to find its value.

Comment: Edited the question. My bad.

Comment: I'm guessing that $( \sqrt{288} + \sqrt{119})^{3/2} - ( \sqrt{288} - \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$ isn't the answer you're looking for? As that *is* the value. What kind of expression are you looking for?

Comment: Is there a specific form you are looking for in the final answer?

Comment: Perhaps [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pa1AryylpM) can help you deduce the answer. Also, see [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5B((sqrt(288)%2Bsqrt(119))%5E(1%2F2)+-+(sqrt(288)-sqrt(119))%5E(1%2F2))*((sqrt(288)%2Bsqrt(119))+%2B+((sqrt(288)%2Bsqrt(119))(sqrt(288)-sqrt(119)))%5E(1%2F2)%2B((sqrt(288)-sqrt(119))))%5D) for some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$I=( \sqrt{288} + \sqrt{119})^{3/2} - ( \sqrt{288} - \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$$
then
$$\begin{aligned}
I^2 &=2\sqrt{288}^3-2\cdot 288\sqrt{288-119}+6\sqrt{288}\cdot 119+2\cdot 119\sqrt{288-119} \\
&= 2\sqrt{288}^3-4394+714\sqrt{288} \\
&= 15480\sqrt{2}-4394.
\end{aligned}$$
Seeing as this can't be "simplified" further, I suspect the "neatest" form is then
$$I=\sqrt{15480\sqrt{2}-4394}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x= (\sqrt{288} + \sqrt{119})^{3/2} - ( \sqrt{288} - \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$$

and $a= (\sqrt{288} + \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$ and $b= ( \sqrt{288} - \sqrt{119})^{3/2}$

then $$a^2+b^2 = 2\sqrt{288}^3 + 6\sqrt{288}\sqrt{119}^2 = 24\sqrt{2}(288+3\cdot 119)$$ $$ab = (288-119)^{3/2}= 13^3 =2197$$

so $$x = \sqrt{(a-b)^2} = \sqrt{15480\sqrt{2}-4394}$$